# Функция постепенного вывода сообщения, Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь написать код для эффекта, как будто бот печатает сообщение прямо в окне чата. Пока все, что получилось придумать, но все равно пока не работает из-за ошибок среза. Буду рад любой помощи.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def type(message):
    orig_text = "Текст для теста"
    textt = orig_text
    tbp = "" 
    typing_symbol = "|"
    mes = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "-")
 
    while(tbp != orig_text):

        textt = await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=mes.message_id, text = tbp + typing_symbol)
        sl(0.05)
 
        tbp = tbp + textt[0]
        textt = textt[1:]
 
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=textt.message_id, text = tbp)
        sl(0.05)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async def echo_message(message):
    orig_text = "123456789"
    msg = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '_')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    tbp = orig_text[:1]
    for x in orig_text[1:]:
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id, text=f'{tbp}_')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        tbp += x
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id, text=tbp)
```