# Имитация набора сообщения telegram telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Кто нибудь знает как сделать так чтобы бот при ответе типа набирал сообщение, а не просто его отсылал  желательно это всё на telethon [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1407981/470333

Comment: Сергей, это не то, но спасибо

Comment: И в чем проблема переделать под telethon?

Comment: Тут проблема что сообщение набирается в самом чате, я вроде уже нашёл решение, сейчас скину

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677154/is-there-a-way-to-send-user-is-typing-status-in-telethon

Comment: Ну хоть уже понял ваш вопрос ))

Comment: Всё равно спасибо)